# Why this PHP code return me always the same echo?

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo

This code is a part of registration code. But it return always "Nickname already exist". I don't understand why.

```
if (isset($_POST['create'])) { 

    $nickname   = $_POST['nickname'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $password   = $_POST['password'];

    $slt1 = "SELECT nickname FROM users WHERE nickname='$nickname'";
    $slt2 = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $stmt1 = $db->prepare($slt1);
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare($slt2);


        if($stmt1->execute([$nickname])) {

            echo 'Nickname already exist';

        } elseif ($stmt2->execute([$email])) {

            echo 'email already exist';

        } else {

            //more code here            

        }

    }
```

Comment: The first `if`'s returning true just means that the query executed successfully.  It says nothing about the business logic behind your query.  To check for that, you'll have to look into the result set.

Comment: also, you use prepare statement completely wrong, you suppose to bind variable using placeholders. Please read PHP's manual [examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to know how to use PDO prepare statement.

Answer (score 1):

The way you use execute is wrong, and what an execute returns is a Boolean value (TRUE/FALSE) but not the number of rows your query has selected/affected.

So you need to get the count of the rows that your query affects and perform the "if" on that value.

Like this,

```
   $stmt1->execute();

   $number_of_rows = $stmt1->num_rows;

   if($number_of_rows == 1){

        echo 'Nickname already exist';
   }
   else{            
   //your code to insert data
   }
```